# Как сделать так чтобы Python код сам считал сколько файлов в папке и по очереди открывал их?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как решить эту проблему? Все файлы в папке есть, путь верный (если писать вручную все открывается корректно)

код

```
from pathlib import Path
import os, random

os.chdir('../src/player/')

for item in Path('.').glob('*'):
    if item.is_file():
        f = open('../src/player/' + str(item), encoding='utf-8')
        f = f.readlines()
        f = [line.rstrip() for line in f]

        print(item, "|", random.choice(f))
```

ошибка

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\PROG\new_bunker\code\test.py", line 8, in <module>
    f = open('../src/player/' + str(item), encoding='utf-8')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../src/player/act.TXT'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Текущая папка уже `'../src/player/'`, добавлять это к имени ещё раз не нужно, `item` готов к употреблению

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, теперь все работает как надо.